# update and also insert new rows with animation in uitableview with one logic step

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

When I'm getting new data from my server  I need to:

1. update existing data for the existing rows of `UITableView` and
2. insert new rows with animation.

The thing is I don't know when `[UITableView reloadData]` is finished for *step 1*,
so I can start *step 2*.

How to deal with this situation?

I prefer to use *step 1* with `[UITableView reloadData]` for simplicity, but any other solution to achieve both steps in one logic step will be cool too.

**UPDATE** - maybe this is my mistake.

it's seems that

-update data model with existing rows info

-reloadData

-update data model with new rows info

-insertWorsAtIndexPaths

works O.K now.

I removed some "ugly" way that force main thread to refresh after step 1, and for now, everything is O.K

(the "ugly way was calling [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0f] , that for some reason I need to add it to work in the past)

Wonder..if everything really O.K now.
Will Update if somthing still wrong.
Sorry for the troubles :)

**update 2**

this is how now I use it and seems to work ok :

-update existing rows in data model, then call

```
[UITableView reloadData];
```

-add new rows to data model, then call

```
[UITableView beginUpdates]

[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPath withRowAnimation]

[UITableView endUpdates]
```

Comment: do you want to run the two steps on separated threads?

Comment: holex, I'm loading the data to entites in background thread, and updating the uitableview in the main thread (well..I must do that on the main thread).

for now, I'm using "ugly" way that also make some bugs on some situations : after reloadData(step 1) I call [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate with 0.0f

The table load the data, and only then I continue with background thread, add NEW entities and then call InsertRows on main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` to update your rows with an animation. Or you can use `reloadData` then `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` it depends how do you get the data.

Check the [UITableView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi, see my reply to holex.
Now, correct me if I'm wrong, if I call reloadData (when the data model hold 10 rows) then add 2 rows entities to the data model , and now call InsertRowsWithAnimation, the reloadData will not work properly cause the data model will have 12 rows.

Comment: Hi, you're right. Just use the reloadSections:withRowAnimation: after you add the two rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a **NSURLConnection**,

If you set the delegate, these method will be called when there is response:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

In these methods you can add your data to the tableview, and do the

```
[UITableView reloadData];
```